# An efficient way to merge 2 large CSS files

Tags: css, merge, minify, compression

I'm looking for a tool that allows you to merge 2 large CSS files. All the ones I've tried so far (like CSSMerge) haven't worked out. Some of them just randomly remove properties. Others choke on the non-standard properties like -webkit and -moz and give me errors. And I also need something that preserves the case of each rule. CSSMerge changed all rules to lower-case.

Comment: Are there duplicate entries in the CSS files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Try

### [CSS Compressor & Minifier](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/)

It have lots of options, you can compress and/or minify css.

- Copy both CSS files into CSS input
- Turn on Sort selectors and properties
- Obtain output
- Manually remove duplicates
- Re-enter input
- compress or minify your output

Comment: this may help http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?s=37cb4bc31c91263a9f471c2211eca4c7&p=896892&postcount=4

Comment: What if one CSS file is over-riding properties of the other?  (e.g., where you have created a Wordpress child theme, and now you want to merge and jettison the original CSS file).  Have people had success in this case?

Comment: I answer my own question: yes, it will merge, and it appears to do a decent job of it.

Comment: This site no longer exists

Comment: @sn3ll yes it is. Don't worry there's lots more https://www.google.com/search?q=minify+css+online

Answer (score 0):

Try SASS, you'll need ruby, but it's awesome for CSS generally. It will merge props though, as well as all it's other awesomeness.