# Sequence of css file imported within a css file

Tags: css, css-import

I have a css file that imports many other css files. What will be sequence of css execution? Which css rules are applied first.? From imported files or the file itself?

Comment: This is already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913131/can-one-css-file-take-priority-over-another-css-file#answer-16913205) and helps you too.

Comment: I was confused with `@import`ing css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be applied in the order you import them. Imported files first, then the file itself.